# I am having trouble assigning the desired variables to my array.

Tags: ruby, loops

I am working on a writing a function for a learning site called 
[code wars](https://www.codewars.com/) my main problem is that I am not able to assign the desired 5 integers as I loop over the given number. I understand from [ruby-doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) that i can assign a array like

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr[1..4] #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which I adapted to be looped over like so

```
digits = 33333339999990000000
ray_a, ray_b = []   
ray_a = digits[start_count, end_count]  
ray_b = digits[start_count + 1, end_count+1]
```

but for some reason as it is looped over it assigns too many digits to the arrays

the actual instructions to the problem as well as my attempt are as follows...

In the following 6 digit number: 283910

91 is the greatest sequence of 2 digits.

Complete the solution so that it returns the largest five digit number found within the number given.. The number will be passed in as a string of only digits. It should return a five digit integer. The number passed may be as large as 1000 digits.

My annotated code... for my testing purposes I passed in 33333339999990000000

```
def solution(digits)
  ray_a = []   # ray_a & ray_b are to be compaired
  ray_b = []

  total_counter = 1 
  start_count = 0
  end_count = 4
  answer = 0

  digits = digits.to_s.split('')  #turns digits into an array of integers
  digits.map!{|x| x.to_i }


  while total_counter<=digits.length do  #carries out as many loops as the variable "digits" has digits

      ray_a = digits[start_count, end_count]  #sets ray_a & ray_b to the numbers to be compaired
      ray_b = digits[start_count + 1, end_count+1]   

    # the above block is where my problem is. At any time each array should have a maximum of 5 digits,
    # instead using the example variable I am passing in as many as 13 digits are assigned 

    # I found the fatal flaw in my code with the debugging block
    # puts "ray_a"
    # print ray_a


    ray_a.map{|x| x.to_s}  #this block turns ray_a & ray_b into indivudal integers that are not arrays. 
    ray_a = ray_a.join('')
    ray_b.map{|x| x.to_s}
    ray_b = ray_b.join('')
    ray_a = ray_a.to_i
    ray_b = ray_b.to_i



    if ray_a > ray_b # this block determines the answer 
          if ray_a > answer
            answer = ray_a 
    end 
      end 



    start_count +=1 #incriments all the counters
    end_count +=1
    total_counter+=1
    ray_a = []# resets both arrays to be redefined in the next loop
    ray_b = []
end 
return answer

 end


 solution(33333339999990000000)
```

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is even after reading this enormous pile of code. Can you come up with a more **minimal** description of the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think i did this problem before. pretty sure he is trying to find a sequence of 5 digits that create the largest 5 digit number out of the string of digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
ray_a = digits[start_count, end_count]
ray_b = digits[start_count + 1, end_count+1]
```

The way you set `ray_a` and `ray_b` is incorrect. What you are doing is

```
ray_a = digits[starting index, length]
```

That is why you the length of your array constantly changes, because you are incrementing `end_count`.

What you need to do is

```
ray_a = digits[start_count..end_count]
```

or

```
ray_a = digits[start_count, 5]
```

and you can remove a variable.